# Run two thread concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I am trying two print two thread's name concurrently. Can any body suggest , what i am doing wrong? I am getting "IllegalMonitorStateException

//ODD THREAD RUNNABLE
    public class OddThread implements Runnable {

```
    MainClass obj;
    public OddThread(MainClass obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.obj= obj;
    }
    public void run() {
        int number=1;
        while(number <10)
        {
          obj.PrintNumbers();
          notifyAll();
          try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println("Exception in wait of OddThread");
        }
          number = number+2;

        }

    }

}
```

//  Even THREAD RUNNABLE

```
public class EvenThread implements Runnable{

    MainClass obj;
    public EvenThread(MainClass obj)
    {
        this.obj=obj;
    }
    public void run() {
        int number=0;
        while(number<=10)
        {
          obj.PrintNumbers();
          notifyAll();
          try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in wait of EvenThread");
        }
       number = number+2;
        }

    }

}
```

// MAIN CLASS

```
public class MainClass {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       MainClass obj = new MainClass();
      // Boolean flag= true;
       EvenThread evenThread = new EvenThread(obj);
       OddThread oddThread = new OddThread(obj);
       Thread Even = new Thread(evenThread);
       Thread Odd = new Thread(oddThread);
       Even.setName("Even Thread");
       Odd.setName("Odd Thread");
       Even.start();
       Odd.start();
   }

   public synchronized void PrintNumbers()
   {
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }

}
```

The output i am getting is 
Even Thread
Odd Thread
Exception in thread "Even Thread" Exception in thread "Odd Thread" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Comment: The default exception handler probably printed a _stack trace_ along with the name of the exception.  The stack trace tells you exactly what your program was doing when the exception was thrown.  Knowing what line of your program threw it, and reading the Javadoc for the method that you called on that line should tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static int number=0;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       MainClass obj = new MainClass();
      // Boolean flag= true;
       EvenThread evenThread = new EvenThread(obj);
       OddThread oddThread = new OddThread(obj);
       Thread Even = new Thread(evenThread);
       Thread Odd = new Thread(oddThread);
       Even.setName("Even Thread");
       Odd.setName("Odd Thread");
       Even.start();
       Odd.start();
   }

   public synchronized void PrintNumbers()
   {  
       while(number<20)
       {
           System.out.println(number+"---"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
           number++;
           notifyAll();

           try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       }
   }

}




public class OddThread implements Runnable {


    MainClass obj;
    public OddThread(MainClass obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.obj= obj;
    }
    public void run() {

          obj.PrintNumbers();


    }

}



public class EvenThread implements Runnable{

    MainClass obj;
    public EvenThread(MainClass obj)
    {
        this.obj=obj;
    }
    public void run() {
        int number=0;

          obj.PrintNumbers();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should surround the `notifyAll()` and `wait()` within `synchronized (this) {}`
like:

```
synchronized (this) {
    notifyAll();
}
```

and

```
synchronized (this) {
    wait();
}
```

these method `notify()`,`notifyAll()`,`wait()` can only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor,so you must surround them in a synchronized block,as is said [Here the Object Java doc](http://This%20method%20should%20only%20be%20called%20by%20a%20thread%20that%20is%20the%20owner%20of%20this%20object's%20monitor)

Comment: Thanks for replying. The method PrintNumbers(), which is being called from run() of both the threads,  is synchronized . So do i still need to add a synchronized block and then call wait and notify in it ?

Comment: synchronized on PrintNumbers() only surround this method,not the next call `notifyAll();`

Comment: My Bad. I was being silly not noticing that after the call of printNumber() the thread will come out of the method and release the lock hence call of notifyAll() or wait() afterwards will always throw IllegalMonitorStateException.